# Brownie Contract creation takes too long

Tags: brownie

The function `Contract.from_abi` in brownie is taking too much time, even after disabling bytecode check with a dirty hack. How can one use Brownie in a meaningful way for a project that loads thousands of `Contract` objects? Currently it takes me 2.5 seconds to create 125 objects. And as I said this is with the hack.